# SQL Join with not like

Tags: mysql, join, sql-like

I'm on MySQL 5.0.

I basically have a List Item table and a List Title table.  For each Title, there can be 60+ items, which are all text.  Dynamically I am trying to get Titles returned that have items people want to include or exclude.  My Query is basically:

```
Select Distinct TitleID from Titles
left join Items on Items.titleID = Titles.titleID
Where Items.Name not like 'Item 2'
```

If any Items have Name like 'Item 2' then I don't want the `TitleID`.  However there could be 59 other Names associated with a Title, so this query is still returning Every possible `TitleID`.

How can I write it so that I only get the `TitleID`s I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select Distinct TitleID from Items
Where TitleID not in (
Select TitleID from Items
Where Name like 'Item 2')
```

There is no wildcard in 'item 2' though, so it does not make much sense.

Comment: Yeah, was just a quick example... that works exactly though!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.TitleID
    FROM Titles t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                         FROM Items i 
                         WHERE i.TitleID = t.TitleID 
                             AND i.Name LIKE 'Item 2%')
```

Comment: Thanks Joe!  Yours is formatted better, I see the similarities to Philip's method as well, though.

Comment: @Neil M. Be sure to test both methods. I suspect mine may perform better (NOT EXISTS vs. NOT IN).